# @nrwl/nest start the server every time I hit save

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nx-workspace

I use NX Workspace with NestJS, and my issue is that every time I save something in the project, the entire program restarts without shutting down the previous app.
[image: The problem]

How could I restart the server?
This is the project.json file (inside the NestApp)

```
{
  ...
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "optimization": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "inspect": false
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/js:node",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "server:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "server:build:development"
        },
      }
    },
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, please upgrade the version. [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/pull/14154)